# Is there evidence to suggest that the Klingons employ the augment virus as a subterfuge technique in Star Trek Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, star-trek-discovery

In Star Trek Enterprise [S4:E16](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Divergence_(episode)) *Divergence* - we see the Klingon experiments with genetic engineering. They appear to borrow the human efforts from the [Eugenics wars](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eugenics_Wars). We see this particularly with the [augment virus](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Klingon_augment_virus) - which changes the appearance of Klingons substantially.

In Star Trek Discovery [S1:E4](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/tv/star_trek_discovery/s01/e04) *The Butcher's Knife Cares Not for the Lamb's Cry* - we see [L'Rell](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/L%27Rell) - of the [House of Mokai](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/House_of_Mo%27Kai) tell [Voq](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Voq) that he must sacrifice everything. [Later](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Choose_Your_Pain_(episode)) we see L'Rell employ her English language skills as her house specialises in spycraft.

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that the Klingons employ the augment virus as a subterfuge technique in Star Trek Discovery?**

Comment: As *Discovery* seems to exist in a different ST universe from *Enterprise* I'm not sure we can connect them in that way.  I don't think the makers are in the least bit concerned about keeping things consistent with other series.

Comment: There's no evidence that Discovery and Enterprise take place in the same universe at all. (except for superficial similarities and CBS telling us they do)

Comment: However I'll be pleasantly surprised if they go that route with the augment virus. (although I thought it was an unnecessary retcon in Enterprise to begin with)

Comment: @StephenG _" I don't think the makers are in the least bit concerned about keeping things consistent with other series."_ I think you're overstating your case here. The existence of the spore drive is a great counterexample for this. It seemingly nullifies all other series (as STD is set _before_ other series in the same universe, yet no one else uses or even mentions the _clearly superior_ spore drive), but that's sort of _why_ the spore drive is so interesting to us. It's highly likely that it will fall into disuse before we chronologically arrive at TOS, and the question is **why**.

Comment: Although there are theories out there stating otherwise, early on it was stated that Discovery takes place in the prime universe and about 10 years before TOS https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/star-trek-discovery-is-in-prime-timeline-apparent_us_59bbe008e4b0390a1564dcb4

Comment: @zabeus Captain Archer is mentioned in STD, so there is some connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlcear if the virus from *ENT* plays any kind of a role, but the following is **one reason why** viewers witness [prime timeline] Klingons looking different than other depictions from various [prime timeline] *Treks*.

> "The empire is very big. **They don’t all grow up on Kronos. They don’t
>   all live on the same planets** and certainly those different planets
>   would have different environments. So how would the cultures have
>   evolved differently?…**We tried to come up with cultural axioms for each
>   house so each looks different and they bear a cultural patina like our
>   cultures do here on Earth.**"
>   https://trekmovie.com/2017/08/03/stlv17-designers-explain-why-star-trek-discovery-klingons-are-bald-and-more/

[image: Star Trek: Discovery - Klingon Communication]

> "What can you say to reassure us that we’re not losing the Klingons we
>   know and love?” a furtive audience member asked during the Q&A
>   portion. Mitchell assured the crowd that the recent publicity still
>   image released was of one Klingon, from one house. “**We will see all 24
>   houses and the leaders among them,” he revealed. The houses will be
>   explored, and the physical and ideological differences between them**.
>   L’Rell is part of two houses, Chieffo explained, and the conflicts
>   arising therein, as well as how she is viewed by the Federation versus
>   her own people, will be explored in
>   depth."http://www.treknews.net/2017/08/03/star-trek-discovery-cast-klingon-houses-stlv/

[image: Discovery]

[image: Discvery 3]

So although it is made clear that there are various houses of Klingons, and that the more familair versions are then limited to Kronos Klingons in other *Treks*, it doesn't explain why that limitation exists.

Some speculation on my part is that because *Discovery* is really a covert cold war story, it could turn out that many of these houses cease to exist (or exist in known parts of space at this time or known times in known *Treks*, in this timeline) by the time of *Discovery's* end.

Comment: Covert cold war? It seems like a pretty open "hot" war to me...

Comment: Yes, because Discovery is sience vessel turned military-weapon vessel, that does not promote "peace" which may be on the verge of defying the prime directorive, and goes against the grain of alot other Treks being so "pro" war. This particular war was only ever mentioned in canon, this is the first time we see how it actually was. And then on top of it, Lorca is refusing to listen to Star Fleet Comand. He is even willing to put a love interest (from higher command) as risk, for the sake of his own beliefs about this war. And then look what he does to Stemmets & what he did to his prev. crew!

Comment: Also Fuller was the original EP on this series, but despite he has was fired, Kurtzman said they were following his draft of the story the best they could. Being a Hannibal (franchise) fan, there are lots of ideas, including these dupliciodous characters like Lorca or Mudd (I know he is TOS character) manipulating others, along with some Hannibal references, that lead me to believe there is some leftover Hannibal influences here. Its a more subversive trek is all I meant--Starfeet wouldn't "brag" about this.